# SQL Server 2012 SSAS Privileges

Tags: sql, ssas

If I install an instance with just SSAS, how is security (login) maintained? I created one instance with engine and SSAS (Dimentional) then another instance with SSAS (Tabular).

Answer (score 1):

There are two main levels for security.

Server/Instance Level Security
this is for server/instance level admins.  These users will have access to server/instance level configuration options as well as all the cubes/tabular models.  To access this, just right click on the SSAS instance and select properties. [linky](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc304417.aspx)

Cube/Model Level Security
this is for cube/model users (people/apps that will be consuming information) and is typically implemented during design time via "roles".  It can also be added/updated after the cube/model is deployed to the server/instance. [linky](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174840.aspx)